# Using parse.com in a java desktop program?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, parse-platform

I have an android app, made in Java using eclipse. It receives push notifications from parse.com just fine but now instead of logging on to parse.com to send the push notifications, I want it to be possible to send notifications from the server (without using a webview; the server is a desktop program in Java).

Can I somehow use the parse SDK in a desktop java program or is there another way to do this? Any help would be great!

PS I googled thoroughly and the docs don't cover java programs (only android).

Comment: But the docs cover the REST-API which can be used from everything that can make HTTP requests. Sending pushes via the REST-API: https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending/REST

Comment: So sorry, I never noticed the rest api! For some reason docs only showed me android, ios and windows. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is a open source library namely [Parse4J](https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/parse4j) where you can use your server with integration of it. Actually, it uses parse REST API as underlying architecture. Parse4j currently does not support sending push notification. However, you can write the send push procedure as cloud function and you can trigger from your server via Parse4j. This actually solves your server send push capability.

Hope this helps.
Regards.

Comment: how can I write REST API using Parse4j ?

Comment: Dear Mahenda; Parse4j is written on top of Parse Rest API. To use Parse4j, visit its github page and follow instruction. Regards.

Comment: can you give me github link ?

Comment: kingspeech can you give me Github link ?